# How to assign a 0 for count if the value doesnt exist in the table

Tags: sqlite

I have a table of ratings

```
      |EMPLOYEE|Rating|
          1       B
          2       B
          3       C
          4      NULL
          5      NULL
          6      NULL
```

and i want to retrieve the count of the grades by each grading like so

```
         Result set
        |Rating|Count|
           A     0
           B     2
           C     1
           D     0
           E     0
```

I used this query but the grades that isnt in the table will jsut appear as null

```
     select rating,count(rating) from table group by rating
```

I also used this query which is basically a pivot of the above result set but for some reason it shows 3 rows of repeating data instead of just 1

```
    select (select count(rating) from table where rating = 'E'),(select count(rating) from table where rating = 'D'),(select count(rating) from table where rating = 'C'),(select count(rating) from table where rating = 'B'),(select count(rating) from table where rating = 'A') from table group by rating
```

Comment: Something like `ifnull(count(rating), 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a table for the assignable ratings then it would be quite simple (and flexible)

e.g. consider :-

Your existing table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (employee TEXT, rating text);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (1,'B'),(2,'B'),(3,'C'),(4,null),(5,null),(6,null);
```

The rating table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rating;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rating (rating);
INSERT INTO rating VALUES('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E');
```

Then :-

```
SELECT rating.rating, (SELECT count(*) FROM mytable WHERE rating.rating = mytable.rating) FROM rating;
```

Results in :-

[image]

## Flexibility

Add some new ratings e.g. as per :-

```
INSERT INTO rating VALUES('X'),('Y'),('Z');
```

And then run:--

```
SELECT rating.rating, (SELECT count(*) FROM mytable WHERE rating.rating = mytable.rating) FROM rating;
```

results in :-

[image]

Comment: i see but isnt creating a table just to hold 5 rows of values a little overkill? or is this ok for database design

Comment: Uhhm sqlite_sequence, a system table (for when AUTOINCREMENT has been  coded) can be a just two values. I doubt that a sinlge 4k page is going to break the bank. :)

Comment: Yes i know, im just wondering if it is a good practice to create a table just to store 5 values for situations like mine